# Drawing Rectangle around difference area

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have a question which i am unable to resolve. I am taking difference of two images using OpenCV. I am getting output in a seperate `Mat`. Difference method used is the `AbsDiff` method. Here is the code.

```
char imgName[15];

Mat img1 = imread(image_path1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); 
Mat img2 = imread(image_path2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

/*cvtColor(img1, img1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(img2, img2, CV_BGR2GRAY);*/
cv::Mat diffImage;
cv::absdiff(img2, img1, diffImage);

cv::Mat foregroundMask = cv::Mat::zeros(diffImage.rows, diffImage.cols, CV_8UC3);

float threshold = 30.0f;
float dist;

for(int j=0; j<diffImage.rows; ++j)
{
    for(int i=0; i<diffImage.cols; ++i)
    {
        cv::Vec3b pix = diffImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);

        dist = (pix[0]*pix[0] + pix[1]*pix[1] + pix[2]*pix[2]);
        dist = sqrt(dist);

        if(dist>threshold)
        {
            foregroundMask.at<unsigned char>(j,i) = 255;
        }
    }
}

sprintf(imgName,"D:/outputer/d.jpg");
imwrite(imgName, diffImage);
```

I want to bound the difference part in a rectangle. `findContours` is drawing too many contours. but i only need a particular portion. My diff image is [image: here]

I want to draw a single rectangle around all the five dials.

Please point me to right direction.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. binarize the image with a threshold. Background will be 0.
2. Use `findNonZero` to retrieve all points that are not 0, i.e. all foreground points.
3. use `boundingRect` on the retrieved points.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image (grayscale)
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Binarize image
    Mat1b bin = img > 70;

    // Find non-black points
    vector<Point> points;
    findNonZero(bin, points);

    // Get bounding rect
    Rect box = boundingRect(points);

    // Draw (in color)
    Mat3b out;
    cvtColor(img, out, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    rectangle(out, box, Scalar(0,255,0), 3);

    // Show
    imshow("Result", out);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would search for the highest value for i index giving a non black pixel; that's the right border.

The lowest non black i is the left border. Similar for j.

Answer (score 1):

Find contours, it will output a set of contours as `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>` let us call it `contours`:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> all_points;
size_t points_count{0};
for(const auto& contour:contours){
    points_count+=contour.size();
    all_points.reserve(all_points);
    std::copy(contour.begin(), contour.end(),
              std::back_inserter(all_points));
}
auto bounding_rectnagle=cv::boundingRect(all_points);
```